# How to process Thumbs.db file inside Ruby On Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thumbnails

In my application is needed display large image gallery. For each gallery folder is Thumbs.db file.

Is any possibility inside Ruby On Rails application display/process Thumbs.db file? I cannot build own thumbnail system, because I have only read access to image gallery.

It would be great if for end user I displayed Thumbs.db small images, when user clicks on small image then is display original image.

Any ideas, any gem?

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs.db is an OLE compound document.  You should be able to do this with something like http://code.google.com/p/ruby-ole/.

But OLE is an old Microsoft desktop technology, it's not the sort of thing to bring to web apps.  You're much better off writing your own thumbnail system or using some thumbnail gem.

Comment: I cannot build own thumbnail system, because I have only read access to image gallery. This gallery is owned by other organization structure and they all are using Microsoft tools etc

Comment: You have a weird problem. It should be possible to extract the tumbnails with ruby-ole, but no one has a ready to go gem that does everything.